# Sort List according to names in C# using Linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Here is where I get a new customer when the user saves the customer information. I have a List called allcustomers where I store the customer object. So I generate a list of customers on my summary list with all the customer information. But I want to be able to use linq query to sort the names alphabetically in the Listbox. Here is my code for that, it doesn't sort the names. Any suggestions?

```
List<Customer> allCustomers = new List<Customers>();

private void saveCustomerBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lNameTextBox.Text.Length > 0 && addressTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
    {                
        Customer aCustomer = new Customer(lNameTextBox.Text, addressTextBox.Text, Convert.ToDouble(idTextBox.Text), aReservation);
        conCustLabel.Text = "Customer Information has been saved!";

        allCustomers.Add(aCustomer);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No data has been entered, Please enter the information!");
    }
}

private void sNameBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    summaryListBox.Items.Clear();

    foreach (Customer aCustomer in allCustomers)
    {                
        var sortNames = from Customer in allCustomers
                        orderby Name ascending   
                        select Name;

        if (sortNames.Any())
        {
            summaryListBox.Items.Add(aCustomer.DisplayCustomers());
        }             
    }                    
}
```

Comment: There is no need of the external foreach and the if. Just do the sort and then set the DataSource of the summaryListBox to sortNames.ToList(); unless the DisplayCustomers doesn't simply return the customer name

Comment: Your code seems to have a problem - you are doing `orderby Name` without defining `Name` anywhere? You should be doing `orderby` something in `Customer` i.e. `Customer.Name`? Also, you shouldn't be using your `Customer` type as the range variable in your LINQ, so `from aCust in allCustomers orderby aCust.Name select aCust.Name`

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure I quite understand what you are asking, but if you just want all the Customers to be added in alphabetic order, I think you can just change your `sNameBtn_Click()` method to this:

```
private void sNameBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    summaryListBox.Items.Clear();
    summaryListBox.Items.AddRange(allCustomers.OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => x.DisplayCustomers()));                 
}
```

Comment: Apparently `Customer` contains multiple fields so you need a `Select`.

Answer (score 0):

First sort the list then loop through and it to the list item.

```
summaryListBox.Items.Clear(); allCustomers = (from Customer in allCustomers orderby Customer.Name ascending select Customer).ToList(); foreach (Customer aCustomer in allCustomers) {  summaryListBox.Items.Add(aCustomer.DisplayCustomers());  }
```